# Remove element from object in type script

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have object and there are some elements i don't want them (ex: 'id'), there is any way to exclude this elements from object in type script.

Comment: I need in type script

Comment: A valid JavaScript is essentially TypeScript. And if you look at the solution provided, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `delete` JavaScript operator.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

```js
const obj = { id: 1 }
console.log(obj)

delete obj.id
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: OK thanks, just i have confuse between java script and type script because there is difference in syntax